# specify mimetype for xdmp:document-filter

Tags: marklogic

When I execute `xdmp:document-filter()` on a plain-text email node it takes up to a second to extract the metadata. I have created a post-commit trigger to update documents using this function. Without the trigger mlcp is 50 times faster and there are no timeout errors.

Is it possible to specify options to help speed up the function. e.g.

```
xdmp:document-filter(doc('/some-uri'), 
   <options ...>
      <data-type>email</data-type>
   </options>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using an MLCP transform to run this document-filter function. Triggers take overhead, and the task server will compete for resources with your MLCP ingest.

Once you have it in a transform, you can pace MLCP up or down to find the optimum ingest speed. I typically take a number of threads equal to the total vm/hyper-thread cores. You can also consider using -fastload..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks! I will try out a transform and look into fastload.